# combine regex in python

Tags: python, regex

After collecting user input for various conditions like

I want to extract this pattern,
FCW2110002L

in this first 3 are alphabets,then 7 any numbers between[0-9] and then 1 alphabet

so I make this script for above problem,

```
s = raw_input('Enter yr sentance:')
#s= "this is my id FCW2110002L"
import re

num = re.findall(r'[fF]{1}[cC]{1}[wW]{1}[0-9]{7}[a-zA-Z]{1}',s)

if len(num) == 0:
    print('not found. pls enter correct number')
else:
    for i in num:
        print(num)
```

---

Now, I want to add another condition 
JMX2047X00R

In this 1'st three are letters as above,then total 4 digit between[0-9],then one letter[a-z] then two digit[0-9] and last one letter[a-z]

How can i combine this second condition in my above program?

I also make script for this second program but don't know how to combine both Regular Expression.

second script are as below:-

```
s = raw_input('Enter yr sentance:')
#s= "this is my id JMX2047X00R"

import re

num = re.findall('[jJ]{1}[mM]{1}[xX]{1}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}',s)

if len(num) == 0:
    print('not found. pls enter correct number')
else:
    for i in num:
        print(num)
```

How to combine this two regular expression? please help to combine this regex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

s = raw_input('Enter yr sentance:')

## s= "this is my id FCW2110002L"

import re

num = re.findall(r'[fF]{1}[cC]{1}[wW]{1}[0-9]{7}[a-zA-Z]{1}|[jJ]{1}[mM]{1}[xX]{1}

```
     [0-9]{4}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}',s)
```

if len(num) == 0:

```
print('not found. pls enter correct number')
```

else:

```
print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be simplified, remove the unecessary `{1}` and use the flag `IGNORECASE`. Then join your 2 regex with the or `|` operator:

```
import re

s = raw_input('Enter your sentence:')
num = re.findall(r'fcw\d{7}[a-z]|jmx\d{4}[a-z]\d\d[a-z]', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

if len(num) == 0:
    print('not found. pls enter correct number')
else:
    for i in num:
        print(num)
```

Answer (score -1):

What about using a multiple pattern?

```
s = raw_input('Enter yr sentance:')
#s= "this is my id FCW2110002L"
import re

multi_pattern = r'([fF]{1}[cC]{1}[wW]{1}[0-9]{7}[a-zA-Z]{1}|[jJ]{1}[mM]{1}[xX]{1}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1})'

num = re.findall(multi_pattern, s)

if len(num) == 0:
    print('not found. pls enter correct number')
else:
    for i in num:
        print(num)
```

This is not necessarily the most optimised solution for your problem, but it's likely to allow you to move on.

Comment: You should factor out the silly `{1}` repetitions, there is no need to specify a repetition at all when there is only one of something.

Comment: @Edword 
Enter yr sentance:hi this is my id jmx1234i34h.please also add this id jmx4321h88c

The above inputs shows me 

['jmx1234i34h', 'jmx4321h88c']
['jmx1234i34h', 'jmx4321h88c']
this double output.

Comment: It seems to make sense since we have a multiple pattern and a string with multiple potential matches.